# Finding a minimum equivalent graph of a digraph

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, reference-request

It is said that this problem is NP-complete but I couldn't find the proof.
Is there any paper on this problem or not?

Comment: Could you explain what an "equivalent graph" is?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Not an "equivalent graph", but a "minimum equivalent graph" - the whole phrase is a term of art. Per the paper that introduced the concept, a minimum equivalent graph of *G* is a "smallest subgraph *G’* of *G* such that there is a path from vertex *u* to vertex *v* in *G’* whenever there is a path from *u* to *v* in *G*." This is *almost* the same as a "transitive reduction", except that a minimal equivalent graph is required to be a subgraph (i.e. you can't add edges) but a transitive reduction isn't (i.e. you may - and sometimes must, to minimise edge count - add new edges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem (or more precisely, its decision version) lies in NP, as a small enough equivalent digraph would give an NP-certificate.
What remains is to show that this problem is NP-*hard*.

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0205040) shows that finding a minimum equivalent digraph is NP-hard even when restricted to digraphs with cycles of length at most $5$, via a reduction from SAT. This means that the problem in general is NP-hard and therefore also NP-complete.